# How to start to build a corpus for NLP research

Tags: nlp

I am trying to build an NLP corpus for an under resource language, as there is no data available for the purpose of NLP research. Can any one suggest, how to build or proceed to make it a standard NLP corpus, any standard method or paper or link.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you found or tried so far?  There are many different areas of corpus linguistics and many different methods for collecting the data.  For a rarer / less "digital" language, it's more labor intensive in terms of field work & not typically an area for programmers.

Comment: the language I am trying to work has very less digital resource. so I am trying to build one for NLP research purpose, No doubt it will be a laborious task, but I need technical information too, or is there any standard format by which corpus were build for language like English found in different Universities.

Comment: You should really consult a linguistics department, especially one skilled in collecting corpora for less studied languages.  This is often undertaken by master's or PhD students as part of a long process.  It's not so easy to sit down and do anew.  This isn't meant to dissuade you as much as it is a reflection that collecting such data is pretty expensive per, say, thousand sentences (or million words, if you prefer).  Having a good plan that has been executed before helps keep the cost down and improves the SNR in the data.

Comment: Is there already a set of tags for this language?  I can't tell if you are wanting a tool that takes a user through each word in a "document" and makes it easy for the user to select a tag, or if you are trying to build set of tags.

Comment: What in the world do you mean "there is no data available"? That's pretty darned bogus.  There are many corpora available, including stuff with varying amounts of markup.

Comment: @tchrist the language am working right now has no sufficient data available in digital form. Hence I was trying to build a corpus and digitized the langauge.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest contacting someone like Fei Xia at the University of Washington who has worked on the Penn Treebank and is kind of an expert of hat, or some of the people at Penn.

Building a full on treebank for parsing and tagging is not a trivial task. What exactly are you trying to do? What's the goal?
-parsing/tagging?
-semantics?
-information extraction?
-phonetics?

Honestly, as per the comments, this sounds like a project for an entire team of linguists.